# Laravel 5.2 - Blade link

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm new in laravel, I'm creating the layout structure, I would like know how can transform to blade this section:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
```

with css and scripts I know how do it, but this have sizes and other attributes.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's no need to change that to Blade, beyond maybe running the asset URLs through the `asset()` helper. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change this section of code, because It's not needed